# Why is the sample AWS Lambda Function for "BookAppointment" not working with the AWS Lex sample bot that schedules dentist appointments?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am using the sample for both, and I have tried both v1 and v2, but I get this error on fulfillment of the intent.

[image]

Why is this so? Is it my AWS account or something else?
I have tried linking the Lambda Function as codehook and also for the validation, but it still doesn't work with any combination.

Comment: Can you add way more information to your question? What code are you using? Or at least link the samples you're referring to? Have you checked the specifications of the response that Amazon Lex expects? What does the actual response look like? What have you done yourself to try to fix this issue?

Comment: @stijndepestel thanks for the reply! The samples codes are written in Python. I can't seem to link them, but there are only 3 samples functions made for Lex, and the dentist appointment sample is one of them. Yes, I have read the documentation, and the dialogAction and the other elements in the response are in compliance with the format provided by Amazon. Moreover, I have spent 2 days trying every solution suggested on the internet, as I am not the only one who faces this type of issue. I have tried to mimic other people's tutorials but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you update your question with some code or something? Right now it's impossible to understand what the problem is, let alone how we could help you diagnose and fix it.

Comment: There are two main possibilities at play. 1 - your Lambda function is failing during execution due to unexpected input or an unhandled error. 2 - your Lambda function is returning a response to Lex in the incorrect format. Ensure that you have Cloudwatch logging enabled and that you're debugging the input and the final response. If you could share some of this info perhaps we will be able to assist better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that AWS updated the Amazon Lex "MakeAppointment" example bot to V2 and it caused a change in the input and output response structure for the lambda function. But unfortunately, the lambda function blueprint "lex-make-appointment-python" is still having the old code which expects a bit different structure of event(input from Lex) and returns a different structure of response which is not acceptable by Lex V2.

**Solution:**
It seems that we need to update the Lambda function code to return the desired response as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html#lambda-response-format).